# Sip Servlets clustering on wildfly

Tags: wildfly, sip, restcomm, mobicents-sip-servlets, sip-servlet

I have started using Mobicents (aka Restcomm) sip servlets with Wildfly 10 but even i could not find a clear answers in documentation or anywhere else for questions i have below.

1) Do sip servlets support standalone-ha model such as in a sip dialog fail over scenario? For example in an established call, if node one fails will node to accept subsequent invites or return a 404 like response .

2) Is it required to use Mobicents (aka Restcomm) load balancer even if there is a sip load balancer in front of the servers ?

3) Does the sip application configuration,code etc.. change between standalone and standalone-ha mode? Or it is handled by Wildfly, ActiveMQ, Infinispan?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need clustering if you already have a load balancer? The load-balancer should automatically route the traffic to healthy servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Restcomm SIP Servlets on Wildfly 10 doesn't support replication yet. Only Restcomm SIP Servlets on Wildfly 7 supported product from TeleStax supports replication, Wildfly 10 is expected to be supported later this year.

2) Nope but you need to make sure your load balancer can support SIP Session affinity to always route messages from a given dialog to the same node.

3) No changes should be needed to the application. Only be conscious of what you replicate as it adds overhead in terms of network traffic and memory usage.

Comment: Thanks, that was real helpful.